# using cgscenegraph, how can i have a callback function on animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, frameworks

I made an animation, and i want to add a callback function at the end of the animation loop.

Do you know how I can do that ?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad to read you found your solution :)
You can find a complete example on the cgscenegraph website:
http://gwennaelbuchet.github.com/cgSceneGraph/examples/03_Animation/animation_01_SRT/index.html

There are other examples related to animation also: http://gwennaelbuchet.github.com/cgSceneGraph/examples.html

What you have to understand with the animation engine is that a timeline is generated for each  couple node+property you want to animate. And it is this timeline that provides events related to the animation.

Here is an example to get the onAnimationEnd of a timeline:

```
this.sceneGraph.getTimeline(myNode, "rotation.angle").onAnimationEnd = function (event) {
    console.log("animation ended");
};
```

To get onAnimationStart or onAnimate events, it's exactly the same :)

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

okay i found what i want,

there is a property named "onAnimationEnd" into the CGSGTimeline class that is fired at the end of the animation, so i've got my callback function ;)

for information, there are other callback functions like "onAnimate" & "onAnimationStart" in the cgSceneGraph framework.
link to http://gwennaelbuchet.github.com/cgSceneGraph/api.html

best regards.